# How to give an td a rowspan

Tags: html

On my html , I'm trying to give `rowspan=2` to my `td`. The issue is that the `td` don't go down and take the row. May be I miss something?

I tried to add more `tr` and `td` but it's still not good. Maybe I need to add something?
**UPDATE**
added my css.

```
    module.exports = (data) => {

 
    return `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }
    
            body {
                width: 90%;
                padding: 0 10px;
                margin: 0px;
                min-height: 1350px;
                background-color: #fff;
            }
    
    
            .pageWrapper {
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                direction: rtl;
                padding: 0 15px;
    
            }
    
            .header {
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
            }
    
            .header img {
                display: block;
                width: 350px;
                /* height: 120px; */
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 0;
                border:0 none !important;
               background-color: transparent !important;
    
            }
    
    
            .header h1,
            .header h2 {
                text-align: center;
                display: block;
            }
    
            .header h1 {
                font-size: 1.5rem;
            }
    
            .header h2 {
                font-size: 1rem;
            }
    
            h3 {
                background-color: #D3D3D3;
    
            }
    
            table {
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
                // border-collapse: collapse;
                margin: 0 auto;
                background-color: #fff;
                margin: 0;
    
            }
    
            table.newPage {
                margin-top: 10px;
            }
    
            tbody,
            tr,
            th,
            thead {
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
            }
    
            tr {
                display: block;
            }
    
            tbody {
                border: 1px solid #2c2b7d;
            }
    
            thead {
                background-color: #2c2b7d;
                color: #fff;
            }
    
            th {
                padding: 4px;
            }
    
            tbody th {
                text-align: right;
                padding: 2px;
                border-top: 1px solid #2c2b7d;
                color: #2c2b7d;
                text-decoration: underline;
                font-size: 0.9rem;
            }
    
            td {
                display: inline-block;
                position: relative;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                min-height: 33px;
                border-left: 1px solid #2c2b7d;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #2c2b7d;

            }
    
            td:not(:first-child) {
                margin-right: -5px;
            }
    
            td:last-child {
                border-left: none;
            }
    
            td.col-1 {
                width: 8.33333333%;
                
            }
            td.col-1-nobroder {
              width: 8.33333333%;
              border-bottom : none;
          }
    
            td.col-2 {
                width: 19.9%;
            }
    
            td.col-2-email-firstTb {
                width: 39.75%;
            }
    
            td.col-2-email {
                width: 31%;
                padding-bottom: 3px;
            }
            td.col-2-email-noborder {
              width: 31%;
              padding-bottom: 3px;
              border-bottom : none;
          }
    
            td.col-2-CoverNameAgent {
                width: 34.90%;
            }
    
            td.col-2-rhisoynumber {
                width: 14.5%;
            }
            td.col-2-rhisoynumber-noborder {
              width: 14.5%;
              border-bottom : none;
          }
  
            td.col-2-carkind {
                width: 10.35%;
            }
    
            td.col-2-shildanumber {
                width: 15%;
            }
    
            td.col-3-second-section {
                width: 19.5%;
            }
    
            td.col-3 {
                width: 25%;
            }
    
            td.col-4 {
                width: 33.3333333333333%;
            }
    
            td.col-5 {
                width: 41.6666666666667%;
            }
    
            td.col-6 {
                width: 50%;
            }
    
            td.col-7 {
                width: 58.3333333333333%;
            }
    
            td.col-8 {
                width: 66.6666666666667%;
            }
    
            td.col-9 {
                width: 75%;
            }
    
            td.col-10 {
                width: 83.3333333333333%;
            }
    
            td.col-11 {
                width: 91.6666666666667%;
            }
    
            td.col-12 {
                width: 100%;
            }
    
            td span {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                font-size: 0.7rem;
                color: #2c2b7d;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-align: right;
                padding-right: 3px;
                white-space: nowrap
            }
    
            td p {
                display: block;
                /* position: absolute; */
                /* top: 2px; */
                /* right: 5px; */
                font-size: 0.7rem;
                text-align: center;
                width: 100%;
                color: #000;
                white-space: nowrap;
                /* background-color: #D3D3D3; */
    
            }
    
            td img {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                max-height: 29px;
            }
    
            td p.trems {
                position: relative;
                text-align: right;
                width: 95%;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
                direction: rtl;
                font-size: 0.6rem;
            }
    
            label {
                font-size: 0.7rem;
                position: relative;
                top: -2px;
            }
    
            .checkbox {
                width: 12px;
                height: 12px;
                position: reletive;
                padding-right: 1px;
                padding-bottom: 2px;
                top: 30px;
                right: 20px;
                border-radius: 3px;
                display: inline-block;
                border: 1px solid #2c2b7d;
                color: #2c2b7d;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
    
            .first-section-border {
                border: 2px solid black;
    
    
            }
    
            .section-border-small {
                border: 2px solid black;
                width: 20%;
                height: 100%;
                border-spacing: 0 margin-bottom: 20px;
            }
    
            .section-border {
                border: 2px solid black;
                width: 78%;
                border-spacing: 0
            }
    
            .second-section-border {
                border: 2px solid black;
                width: 100%;
            }
    
            .small-font {
                font-size: 9px;
                text-align: center;
                margin-bottom: 6px
            }
            .small-font-secTwo{
              font-size: 9px;
              text-align: center;
              margin-bottom: 6px;
              border-bottom : none;
            }
    
            .small-font-span {
                font-size: 8px;
                text-align: center;
    
            }
    
            .small-td {
                width: 14%;
                border-bottom : none;
            }
    
            .col-1-name-and-firma {
                width: 12%;
            }
    
    
            .name-and-firma {
                padding: 0;
                // margin-bottom: 1px;
                font-size: 11px;
            }
    
            .your-fault {
                font-size: 10px;
                max-width: 5px;
                margin-bottom: 4px;
                text-align : center;
            }
    
            .your-fault-width {
                font-size: 10px;
                max-width: 5px;
                margin-bottom: 4px width: 12%;
            }
    
            .your-fault-bitohLemui {
                font-size: 10px;
                max-width: 5px;
                margin-bottom: 4px word-wrap:break-word;
            }
    
            input[type='checkbox'] {
                /* Double-sized Checkboxes */
                -webkit-transform: scale(1);
                /* Safari and Chrome */
                transform: scale(1);
                margin-top: 1px;
                margin-right: 5px;
    
            }
    
    
    
            .margin-top {
                margin-top: 1px;
            }
    
            .col-1-ishurEhagastTviaa {
                width: 50%;
                border-bottom: none;
            }
    
    
            .col-2-thiurKlali {
                height: 50px;
            }
    
    
    
            .signAndDate {
                width: 20%;
                text-align: right;
                border: none;
            }
    
            .signAndDateFont {
                font-size: 15px;
            }
    
            .width20point4 {
                width: 20.4%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="pageWrapper">

<!-- Part 4 -->
<table class="first-section-border">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 20%; ">1,1</td>
                    <td style="width: 20%;">1,2</td>
                    <td style="width: 20%; ">1,3</td>
                    <td rowspan=2 style="width: 20%;">1-2,4</td>
                    <td rowspan=2 style="width: 20%;">1-2,4</td>
                </tr>

                <tr >
                    <td style="width: 20%; ">2,1</td>
                    <td style="width: 20%; ">2,2</td>
                    <td style="width: 20%; ">2,3</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>

<img src="file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/htmlIWithPdf/assets/bth.jpg" >
</div>
</body>
</html>

`
}
```

Comment: Youre markup is totally messed up and invalid.

Comment: [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).

Answer (score 0):

1st: You need use `<tr>` tag for conclude the first block of `<td>` tags (a columns must be inside a row).

2nd: The amount of columns in each row in the table must be equal (argument `rowspan="2"` of `<td>` (e.g. `<td rowspan="2">...</td>`) tag means "minus one column in the next row under this cell").

**--- UPDATE 1 ---**
Generally, `<table>...</table>` has syntax (in common view):

```html
<table>
    <thead> <!-- Header section -->
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1 title</th>
            <th>Column 2 title</th>
            ...
            <th>Column N title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> <!-- Body of table -->
        <tr>
            <td>Cell (row 1 col 1)</td>
            <td>Cell (row 1 col 2)</td>
            ...
            <td>Cell (row 1 col N)</td>
        </tr>
        ...
        <tr>
            <td>Cell (row M col 1)</td>
            <td>Cell (row M col 2)</td>
            ...
            <td>Cell (row M col N)</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot> <!-- Table footer -->
        <tr>
            <td>Col.1 footer</td>
            <td>Col.2 footer</td>
            ...
            <td>Col.N footer</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Of course you can exclude any section with all its elements.
**--- END OF UPD.1 ---**

Use this for example:

```html
<!DOCTYPTE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table {
                border: 1px solid #000;
            }
            td {
                border: 1px dotted #00F;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 13%; ">1,1</td>
                    <td style="width: 14.5%;">1,2</td>
                    <td style="width: 13%; ">1,3</td>
                    <td rowspan=2 style="width: 29%;">1-2,4</td>
                    <td rowspan=2 style="width: 30.5%; ">1-2,5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 40.5%;  margin-right : 0.3px;">2,1</td>
                    <td style="width: 40.5%;  margin-right : 0.3px;">2,2</td>
                    <td style="width: 40.5%;  margin-right : 0.3px;">2,3</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**--- UPDATE 2 ---**
After you update your code, I think the issue is caused by styles inside the `<style>...</style>` (without them all is right). Are you sure you need to reverse the order of columns by CSS? Maybe more easy way is to put to the columns values in reverse order to the table instead of using a lot of amout of styles?
**Try to remove unwanted styles or rewrite them.**
P.S.: I hope I correctly understood the essence of your question and was able to provide the necessary advice.
**--- END OF UPD.2 ---**

Comment: hey thank you for your answer. I added my css beacuse your html dont work with my css. can you take a look?

Comment: It looks like right ;-)
..or you have anything else questions?

Comment: In your new code the issue is caused by styles inside the <style> tag (without them all is right).
Are you sure you need to reverse the order of columns by CSS? Maybe more easy way is to put to the columns the values in reverse order to the table instead of using a lot of amout of styles?

Comment: P.S.: In my example the styles are used for demonstration of the borders of <td> elements.